# Applying rules in sequential order to implement hierarchy

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to apply a series of rules and change values if the conditions are met. Ideally, I'd like to avoid loops, and have a large data set (12.5 million observations), so efficiency would be nice (but this only needs be done once, so efficiency not critical).

The sample data looks like this. Each `id` can be present on multiple `date`s, on each of those dates can have multiple `cc`

```
set.seed(1)
id <- 1:200
date <- sample(seq(as.Date('2007/01/01'), as.Date('2012/12/31'), by="day"), 1000, replace=T)
cc <- sample(1:150, 1000, replace=T)
df <- data.frame(id, date, cc)
head(df)

id      date  cc
1 2011-04-28  69
2 2007-05-31 107
3 2012-08-02 100
4 2011-07-04  98
5 2010-08-20 147
6 2009-02-28  51
```

The hierarchy rules have been set up like this:

```
year <- rep(2007:2010, each=8)
ifcc <- c(5,7,8,9,15,16,17,18)
r1 <- c(112,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r2 <- c(8,9,10,NA,NA,NA)
r3 <- c(9,10,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r4 <- c(10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r5 <- c(16,17,18,19,NA,NA)
r6 <- c(17,18,19,NA,NA,NA)
r7 <- c(18,19,NA,NA,NA,NA)
r8 <- c(19,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)

h <- rbind(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8)
h <- cbind(ifcc, h)
h <- data.frame(year, h)

head(h)
year ifcc  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
2007    5 112 NA NA NA NA NA
2007    7   8  9 10 NA NA NA
2007    8   9 10 NA NA NA NA
2007    9  10 NA NA NA NA NA
2007   15  16 17 18 19 NA NA
2007   16  17 18 19 NA NA NA
```

For every `id`/`date` combination, I need to check the hierarchy table for rules (for that year, as they change each year). If the condition category `cc` in `df` matches the hierarchy rule `ifcc` in `h`, then if any of the values in `h$V2`-`h$V7` are present for that `id`/`date` combination in `df`, the rows that match `h$V2` to `h$V7` need to be dropped from `df`.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the lookups and application of the hierarchies. there is SAS code which is not only for one year at a time and a series of manually types out if/then statements. Someone has given it a go (http://healthydatascience.com/cms_hcc.html) but not quite for this scale/multiple years and so many repeated measures...

I'm able to iterate through with loops and create a logical matrix of matches, but takes a while for only 30k lookups, not feasible to scale to 12.5m.

```
t <- matrix(nrow=nrow(df), ncol=nrow(h))
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(h)){
  t[j,i] <- df[j,"cc"] == h[i,"ifcc"]
  }
}
```

I also can't figure out how to use this matrix as a basis for applying the hierarchy rules.

This question directly relates to discussions here:
https://github.com/jackwasey/icd/issues/31
https://github.com/anobel/icdtohcc/issues/1

#### Update

I was able to come up with a functioning solution using a loop.
    h$cc <- h$ifcc

```
# Merge hierarchy rules with patient data
df <- merge(df, h, all.x = TRUE)

###########
# create empty list
todrop <- list()

# create a list of dataframes that contain the CCs that will be zero'd out
for (i in 1:6) {
  todrop[[i]] <- df[!is.na(df$ifcc),c(1,2,3+i)]
}

# rename all dfs in list to same column names, rbind into one df
todrop <- lapply(1:length(todrop), function(x) {
  names(todrop[[x]]) <- c("id", "admtdate", "cc")
  return(todrop[[x]])
  }
)
todrop <- do.call(rbind, todrop)

# set flag, all of these CCs will be dropped
todrop$todrop <- T

# merge drop flags with pt data
df <- merge(df, todrop, all.x=T)
df <- df[is.na(pt$todrop), ]
```

Comment: should line `h <- cbind(ifcc, cols)` read `h <- cbind(ifcc, h)`? Otherwise previous line's output is lost.

Comment: @RichardTelford yes, thank you, fixed

Comment: Any reason not to just write the loop in RCpp? Should run as fast as vectorised solution in R, and be quick to implement since you already have the R code for it..

Comment: no...I just don't know how to do that! also, aside from creating the matrix with the loop I've shown, I can't figure out how to use the resulting matrix to implement the actual hierarchy rules

Comment: Not sure I exactly understand "each id/date in the df table needs to have the cc set to zero/NA/removed if it is in V2-V7 columns."  Is it possible to phrase this slightly more clearly?

Comment: just edited the question. did that clarify the problem @dww?

Comment: Yes, that's easier to follow now.

Comment: @ano Can you please elaborate the line `then if any of the values in h$V2-h$V7 are present for that id/date combination in df, the rows that match h$V2 to h$V7 need to be dropped from df`? Does that mean that if there is a tuple in h satisfying the condition (i.e. df$cc == h$ifcc and year of df$date == h$year)?

Comment: @KunalPuri that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Alternative Solution using `data.table`:

As you asked for in the question, the code is very much efficient.

.I is the inbuilt functionality provided by data.table which represents the row number of the data table.

```
library(data.table)

## convert data.frame to data.table
setDT(df)

setDT(h)

## find year from date
df[,year := year(date)]

## merge the two datasets with all values of x present

## if order of tuples doesn't matter, please eliminate the sort=F argument
df2 <- merge(df,h[,.(year,ifcc,.I),],by.x = c('year','cc'),by.y = c('year','ifcc'),all.x = T,sort=F)

## obtaining df having NA values
df <- df2[is.na(I),.(id,date,cc)]

## converting back to data.frame (do it only if required)
setDF(df)
```